# Joomla Server Time Zone / User Time zone?

Tags: php, date, datetime, joomla

I'm setting the **Joomla 3** server timezone to: Asia/Bahrain (GMT+3)
The user I'm using timezone is also Asia/Bahrain (GMT+3).

However, I'm storing on the database time values as timezone UTC which later I show it to users as there timezone or the Joomla Server Timezone if This system installed to other client.

than I test:

```
    <?php

    $date = new DateTime(null);
    $tz = $date->getTimezone();
    echo $tz->getName();

    ?>
```

output:

```
America/Denver
```

and,

```
$jdate = JFactory::getDate( '01:00:00' );
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s');
```

output:

```
01:00:00
```

**while it should +3 hours as Joomla server timezone set to +3**

to solve that I wrote:

```
$jdate = JFactory::getDate( '01:00:00' , "Asia/Bahrain" );
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s');
```

**a.is Joomla ignoring it's timezone and user timezone and need me add the timezone every where?Is joomla working like that?**

**c.Where Joomla server timezone is effecting?**

**d.How to make the priority to user timezone than joomla time zone on all Jdate object by default without editing the core of joomla?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: using JHtml::('date' , ....) for output

https://compojoom.com/blog/entry/how-to-use-jdate

Answer (score 0):

When you call `JFactory::getDate()` it will construct a `JDate` object, which already takes the timezone into account.

More info:

- http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_JDate
- http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDate.html
- http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFactory.html#method_getDate

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$jdate = JFactory::getDate( '01:00:00' , "Asia/Bahrain" );
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s'); //outputs 01:00:00
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s',true); //outputs 10:00:00 (!!)

//Versus
$jdate = JFactory::getDate( '01:00:00');
$jdate->setTimezone("Asia/Bahrain");
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s'); //outputs 01:00:00
echo $jdate->format('H:i:s',true); //outputs 04:00:00 (correct)
?>
```

Notice the magic second parameter in format function:

```
boolean $local = false
```

There is also a third optional parameter (I don't know what it does):

```
boolean $translate = true
```

Really, their docs could use some help.